# Load WP content with ajax less server demanding and faster than normal page loading?

Tags: ajax, performance

This is a technical doubt I had after reading some articles about WP ajax process (cannot find them though).

Is it faster and cheaper to load WP content (any content, page, post, widgets etc...) using WP ajax API than making a full canonical page request?

I thought about this because maybe passing through wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is lighter than loading a new page running the whole WP stack altogether.

Am I right?

Comment: thanks @toscho, I noticed there was something strange going on! didn't notice i was in meta :D

Answer (score 3):

No. Let's compare.

Normal load:

1. Access URL.
2. Load WP core.
3. Retrieve stuff from database.
4. Load template file.

Ajaxy load:

1. Accesss URL.
2. Load WP core.
3. Load template file.
4. Load JavaScript.
5. Make Ajax request.
6. Load WP core **(again)**.
7. Retrieve stuff from database.
8. Receive stuff from Ajax.
9. Put into page.

Repeat steps 5-9 for each Ajax request.

Comment: your list is valid for the first page load and in that situation you got a point. But I was referring to sequential calls using ajax instead of reloading the page, for example for pagination or in web apps (ok, don't take in count the SEO stuff)

Comment: I made the same question in stackoverflow and a guy told me that even in the ajax call all the plugins are run again. is that true?

Comment: @Bakaburg yes, you can reuse page and change content with Ajax, but you are making heavy trade-offs in complexity of implementation and ease of caching. And yes, a guy was correct - Ajax endpoint does full WP core load, including plugins and themes. Otherwise they wouldn't work with Ajax.

Comment: themes too?? what for?

Comment: @Bakaburg how do you suppose theme would use Ajax in WordPress if it won't load when Ajax is executed? :) To elaborate, by themes I mean `functions.php` files of active parent & child themes (and of course whatever they choose to further load).

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhh! everyone is giving me a different answer!!!!

Comment: @Bakaburg I'm in one of those rare situations where I want to downvote a comment. Please re-read all of what was given to you by Rarst.